# Prove $\int_{-b}^{\infty}\log^{\nu}(t+b)e^{-t}e^{-e^{-t}}dt\xrightarrow{b\rightarrow\infty} \log^{\nu}(b)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, approximation, approximate-integration

How to prove
\begin{equation}
\int_{-b}^{\infty}\log^{\nu}(t+b)e^{-t}e^{-e^{-t}}dt\xrightarrow{b\rightarrow\infty} \log^{\nu}(b),
\end{equation} 
where $\nu$ is any real or complex number. I have validated this asymptotic in MATLAB with numerical method.

Note that in our previous post (please refer to [How to approximate the integral $\int_{-b}^{\infty}\log(t+b)e^{-t}e^{-e^{-t}}dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010717/how-to-approximate-the-integral-int-b-infty-logtbe-te-e-tdt)), the special case $\nu=1$ was proved by @tired, however, this method only applies to the case $\nu=1$ rather than the general value of $\nu$. There should be a general method to prove it.

Comment: how do you define $\log^{\nu}(z)$ on the interval $z \in \{0,1\}$?

Comment: sorry, I didn't get your concerning...

Comment: for $t+b<1$ the logarithm gets negative. Now we have to answer the question how to take the non-integer exponent of this quantity (you may recall the for example the square root is a multivalued function in the complex plane)

Comment: Take the definition in MATLAB: For negative and complex numbers z = u + i*w, the complex square root sqrt(z) returns
sqrt(r)*(cos(phi/2) + 1i*sin(phi/2))
where r = abs(z) is the radius and phi = angle(z) is the phase angle on the closed interval -pi <= phi <= pi.

Comment: Suppose that $\int_{-b}^{\infty}\log^{\nu}(t+b)e^{-t}e^{-e^{-t}}dt\xrightarrow{b\rightarrow\infty} \log^{\nu}(b)$ holds, if we can prove $\int_{-b}^{\infty}\log^{\nu+\delta}(t+b)e^{-t}e^{-e^{-t}}dt\xrightarrow{b\rightarrow\infty} \log^{\nu+\delta}(b)$, then it accomplish the proof. Is it simpler to prove in such way?